# Using setTimeout inside Model in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, settimeout

I am brand new to backbone, and I am trying to learn it by making a few example apps. One is a soccer manager game. I am trying to make a "match" model, which has a function called "start()", which in theory would start a timer which would count up to 90. Here is my model:

```
var Match = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function(){
        return {
            name: "Match One",
        };
    },
    start: function() {
        console.log("match started");
        this.incrementMinute();
    },
    incrementMinute: function() {
        var min = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            min.set('minute', ++min.minute);
            if(min.minute % 10 === 0)
                min.updateStatus();
            min.incrementMinute();
        }, 3000);
    },
    updateStatus: function() {
        this.set("detail", "Minute is now: "+this.minute);
    },
    minute: 0,
    detail: "Match is about the kick-off..."
});
```

I have a "change" listener attached to `minute` and to `detail`. When the minute or the detail changes my view is updated, this is working properly. However for some reason my browser tab crashes when I get to around the 15th minute mark. The whole tab becomes unresponsive, and eventually it crashes. I have also tried to use `setInterval`, but still the problem exists.

A live version can be found here:

http://bit.ly/188TtWa

**Questions**

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I fix it, or how else should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in your MatchView's render method.

It binds event listeners each time it is called.
Thus after only a view updates, you have a whole lot more event handlers, which all call the render method again.

Try binding events only once instead of every time.
Also, i think you can call _.template(..) only once, too.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, I will try to re-organize this part of the code.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I added an `initialize` function to my MatchView, so that I don't repeatedly initialize with every render function call.